# $f \in L^p(E)$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{p}m(E_n)<+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I made this statement to myself as lemma to prove another statement. Could someone help me to check if this is correct or not?

**Question.** If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, $m(E) <+\infty$, $E_n= \lbrace x\in E \mid n-1 \leq|f(x)|\leq n \rbrace$, then $f \in L^p(E) \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{p}m(E_n)<+\infty$ for $p \in (0,\infty)$.

**Proof.** 
$(\Leftarrow)$ By assumption $E_n= \lbrace x\in E \mid n-1 \leq|f(x)|\leq n \rbrace$, we have
$$
\int_{E_n}|f(x)|^p dx \leq n^p m (E_n),
$$
then taking the summation,
$$
\int_E|f(x)|^p d x \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p m(E_n).
$$
Therefore, since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p m(E_n)<+\infty$, then $f \in L^p(E)$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Use a proof by contradiction. Suppose that the statement "if $f \in L^P(E)$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p m(E_n)=+\infty$" is true. This implies that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n-1)^p m(E_n)=+\infty$, then
$$
+\infty = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)^p m (E_n) \leq \int_E|f(x)|^p d x \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^p m(E_n) = +\infty.
$$
This is a contradiction because $\|f\|_p$ is finite.

Comment: I don't think it's correct. e.g. $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ is $L^1$, but $m(E_1)=\infty$.

Comment: @Vit it is assumed $E_1\subset E$ with $|E|<\infty$. To user1082245: why do you get $\sum (n-1)^p m(E_n) = \infty$?

Comment: Note that your choice of the statement in the proof by contradiction is incorrect.  If you intend it to be "for all $f$," then the contradiction is too weak.  If you intend it to be "for a particular $f$," then there is no contradiction.  The statement you should suppose is true in a proof by contradiction is "For some $f$, $f \in L^p(E)$ _and_ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^pm(E_n) = +\infty$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is true assuming e.g. $f$ measurable, $p\in[1,\infty)$. It seems to me that in the "$\implies$" proof, the claim $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)^p m(E_n) =\infty$ is unjustified. But this is not so hard:  since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p m(E_n)=\infty$ and $m(E_1)<\infty$, we must have $\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^p m(E_n)=\infty$ as well. Hence, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)^p m(E_n) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^p n^p m(E_n) \ge \inf_{k\ge 2} \left(\frac{k-1}k\right)^p \sum_{n=2}^\infty n^p m(E_n) = \frac1{2^p}\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^p m(E_n) = \infty. $$
Therefore, $\|f\|_p^p \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)^p m(E_n)=\infty$ and $f\not\in L^p$.

(note that $\|f\|_p^p \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p m(E_n)=\infty$ is not needed)

Comment: Is this true for $p \in (0,\infty)$?

Comment: @user1082245 yes also, same proof.